# How To Get Chart From Sheet in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I am using Google Apps Script with Spreadsheets. I am trying to find out a way to return a Google Chart(static or dynamic, doesn't matter). The data set that I will be using will be in a spreadsheet, and I want the Google Chart to be returned in the form of a web app(URL should start with: script.google.com/macros/idforscript). I have tried to use the official Google Apps Script tutorials, but even they don't work, leaving me, when I open the page, with a *[400]* error in a red rectangle. Here is the code that I am using:

```
  function doGet() {
  /*
  var data = Charts.newDataTable()
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, 'Month')
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'In Store')
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Online')
      .addRow(['January', 10, 1])
      .addRow(['February', 12, 1])
      .addRow(['March', 20, 2])
      .addRow(['April', 25, 3])
      .addRow(['May', 30, 4])
      .build();
      */
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PPlSIiQ7fZ5AzcyB61iVmIBQQepm6vubd4S2Eo9fWOg/edit#gid=0").getSheets()[0];


  var chart = data.newChart().setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR).addRange(data.getRange('A1:B3')).build();
  var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('My Chart');
  uiApp.add(chart);
  return uiApp;

}
```

Do you know the solution to this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is newCharts().build() function returns a embeddedChart Object:

```
var chart = data.newChart().setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR).addRange(data.getRange('A1:B3')).build();
```

As mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#build()

However, for UiApp you need a chart Object which you should be able to get using setId() method of the embedded Chart object. Unfortunately, using that method raises this error: "Access to class "Chart" is prohibited" error. This issue can be tracked [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761404).

Please also note UiApp has been deprecated since 2014, so not advisable to use for new projects.

Now for a solution and some good news :). Below you will find a modified code which will work with embeddedChart to give you a static chart on your webPage.

Try this:

```
function doGet() {
  /*
  var data = Charts.newDataTable()
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, 'Month')
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'In Store')
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Online')
      .addRow(['January', 10, 1])
      .addRow(['February', 12, 1])
      .addRow(['March', 20, 2])
      .addRow(['April', 25, 3])
      .addRow(['May', 30, 4])
      .build();
      */
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PPlSIiQ7fZ5AzcyB61iVmIBQQepm6vubd4S2Eo9fWOg/edit#gid=0").getSheets()[0];


  var chart = data.newChart().setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR).addRange(data.getRange('A1:B3')).build();
  var blob = chart.getBlob().setContentType('image/jpeg');
  var bytes = blob.getBytes();
  var base64String = Utilities.base64Encode(bytes);
  var html = '<img src="data:' + blob.getContentType() + ';base64,' + base64String + '"/>';
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
}
```

UiApp has been deprecated since 2014. So you will have to use HTML Service to create your content.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app

Hope that helps.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you! @jagannathan